# Android: Constraint Layout Animate Tab Selection

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, android-constraintlayout

I created a custom Tab with ConstraintLayout, I decided to use ConstraintSet and TransitionManager for animating the tab selection.

This is the animation I need.
[image]

But when I implemented the animation I had problems.

**Here is my code:**

*Xml layout definition*

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/card_constraint_canvas"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- View on which I want to apply constraint for animation -->

    <View
        android:id="@+id/tab_selection"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="4dp"
        android:background="@color/colorSoftBlue"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/divider"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>


    <!-- Centered grey divider bar, view which is my anchor point -->

    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorDividerGrey"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

*Java code*

```
@BindView(R.id.tab_selection) View tabSelection;
@BindView(R.id.card_constraint_canvas) ConstraintLayout cardConstraintCanvas;

... 

applyConstraintSet.clone(cardConstraintCanvas); // Working

TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(cardConstraintCanvas); // Working
applyConstraintSet.clear(R.id.tab_selection); // Working
applyConstraintSet.connect(R.id.tab_selection, ConstraintSet.LEFT, R.id.divider, ConstraintSet.RIGHT); // Working
applyConstraintSet.connect(R.id.tab_selection, ConstraintSet.RIGHT, R.id.card_constraint_canvas, ConstraintSet.RIGHT); // Working
applyConstraintSet.connect(R.id.tab_selection, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, R.id.card_constraint_canvas, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM); // Working

// Not working, the animation behaves strange, the tab_selection view disappears, I put 0 as width because I defined in the xml like that (0dp) but not working
// applyConstraintSet.constrainWidth(R.id.tab_selection, 0); 

// Working, but I want my tab_selection view width spread at divider's start edge and parent's end edge after the animation, not a constant dimension
applyConstraintSet.constrainWidth(R.id.tab_selection, 10); 
applyConstraintSet.constrainHeight(R.id.tab_selection, 10); // Working

applyConstraintSet.applyTo(cardConstraintCanvas); // Working
```

I suppose the problem is at constraintWidth. I also try this method for removing only the anchor and maintaining the width and the height.

```
void clear (int viewId, int anchor)
```

But I think it doesn't work as I thought.

Any thoughts?

Thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the line

```
applyConstraintSet.clear(R.id.tab_selection);
```

and change `ConstraintSet.LEFT` and `ConstraintSet.RIGHT` to `ConstraintSet.START` and `ConstraintSet.END` respectively to be consistent with the naming of attributes used in the XML then this animation will work as intended.

I'm not sure why the `clear` method is causing the unwanted behaviour.